# Отслеживание видимости вертикального ScrollBar в ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть `ScrollViewer`:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">

        <local:LogCollectionView/>

    </ScrollViewer>
```

Есть ли свойство, которое позволяет отследить в `ViewModel` виден вертикальный `ScrollBar` или нет? Это необходимо для того, чтобы изменять отступ шапки таблицы, которая находится над этим `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: К VerticalScrollBarVisibility - прибиндить не пробовали?

Comment: @Сергей, нет. Это ведь только свойство отображать его или нет? Или оно изменяется, когда начинается отображение?

Comment: Ну я точно не уверен =)

Comment: @Сергей, на msdn тоже не совсем понятно, есть несколько свойств, которые возможно подходят, но они именно у scrollBar'a. Не могу понять как через scrollViewer к ним обратиться...

Comment: VM не должна знать  виден ли скроллбар в GUI или нет. GUI вообще может не существовать или быть консольным и это не должно повлиять на работоспособность VM. В этом и есть смысл MVVM. Видимость скроллбара и всевозможные отступы это чисто компетенция View.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, хорошо, а как тогда стоит реализовать список с шапкой?
У меня есть отдельное View для шапки, и ScrollViewer, в котором лежит ItemsControl c всеми элементами. Если элементов много, или окно не на весь экран, появляется ScrollBar по вертикали. Как при этом смещать шапку таблицы?

Comment: Написал ответ ↓

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VM не должна знать виден ли скроллбар в GUI или нет. GUI вообще может не существовать или быть консольным и это не должно повлиять на работоспособность VM. В этом и есть смысл MVVM. Видимость скроллбара и всевозможные отступы это чисто компетенция View.

А вообще узнать, видим ли сейчас скроллбар можно заглянув в свойство `ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility`, его изменения удобно отслеживать по событию `ScrollChanged`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyScrollViewer.ScrollChanged += MyScrollViewer_ScrollChanged;
}

private void MyScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var v = MyScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility;
}
```

`v` при этом будет иметь обычный тип `Visibility` и принимать значение `Collapsed` или `Visible`

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать реализовать. Позже отпишу о результате!

Comment: спасибо большое! все прекрасно работает!
Благодаря вам лучше понял суть mvvm.
А не подскажите, как добавить кнопки перемещения в конец и начало скрола? Как их реализовать программно я знаю, а вот как их разместить непосредственно над и под скролом не могу понять...

Comment: Это хороший вопрос - задайте его отдельно

Comment: @UporotayaPanda, переопределить template как вариант