# Прокрутка ScrollBar'a по одному элементу ItemsControl'a

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется ScrollViewer, внутри которого лежит ItemsControl:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="CollectionScroll"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  Style="{StaticResource FavsScrollViewer}">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AllJournal.AllEvents}"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:LogEventView/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Возник вопрос как прокручивать скролл по одному итему при помощи мыши и кнопок на клавиатуре?

Появилась область внизу списка(

[image: Область внизу списка]

Comment: `ListBox` вместо `ItemsControl` не подойдет?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а там эта функция реализуется?

Comment: Да. Попробуйте использовать ListBox, но оборачивающий `ScrollViewer` уберите. А в ListBox напишите `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"`. Может это не то вам нужно...

Comment: @АндрейNOP без скрола никак, очень много элементов. Без скрола пользователь будет долго листать, а так он может всегда переключиться в то место, куда ему нужно. Плюс вы мне недавно очень помогли с разработкой этого скрола, чтобы в нем были кнопки перехода в начало и конец.

Comment: Ну так включите скролл в ListBox. Как-то так: `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>`

Comment: @АндрейNOP это точно позволит скролить через один или несколько итемов?

Comment: Вы попробовали эту разметку?

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, скролит через 1-3 итема(возможно мышка так настроена), но вроде работает)
Только сейчас все стили переписывать(
И как можно реализовать перемещение через определенное количество

Comment: Больше мне вам пока нечего предложить :)

Comment: Та разметка, которая у вас есть сейчас, у вас в ScrollViewer лежит целиком ItemsControl и он его принимает за одно целое. поэтому он не сможет никак ориентироваться на внутренние одиночные элементы...

Comment: Чтобы он видел эти элементы, он должен лежать внутри ItemsControl, у ListBox именно так изначально и сделано

Comment: @АндрейNOP а в ItemsControl такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Да, можно, но придется править шаблон

Comment: @АндрейNOP а не могли бы подсказать/поделиться ссылкой как это сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш `ItemsControl` лежит внутри `ScrollViewer` и выглядит для него как одно целое, для того, чтобы `ScrollViewer` мог различать отдельные элементы внутри `ItemsControl`, он должен сам лежать внутри него. Это можно сделать, изменив шаблон:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
                                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Style>
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <TextBlock Text="0" FontSize="20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="1" FontSize="10"/>
        <TextBlock Text="2" FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBlock Text="3" FontSize="6"/>
        <TextBlock Text="4" FontSize="26"/>
        <TextBlock Text="5" FontSize="18"/>
        <TextBlock Text="6" FontSize="10"/>
        <TextBlock Text="7" FontSize="12"/>
        <TextBlock Text="8" FontSize="22"/>
        <TextBlock Text="9" FontSize="16"/>
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

Обратите внимание, на свойство `CanContentScroll="True"` - именно оно заставляет `ScrollViewer` скролить содержимое "поштучно".

Кстати, например, `ListBox` уже имеет в своем шаблоне `ScrollViewer`, поэтому ему править шаблон не придется, достаточно будет установить свойство `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"`

Количество элементов, которое прокручивается колесиком мыши зависит от настроек системы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы сделать поштучную прокрутку колесиком мыши, можно воспользоваться [этим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/678027/218063):

```
private void OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)sender;
    int p = e.Delta > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollViewer.VerticalOffset - p);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, работает!
Вот только появилась область внизу списка(добавил скрин в вопрос)

Comment: @UporotayaPanda, добавил еще в ответ как прокручивать поштучно колесом мыши. А вот с пустым местом вряд ли можно сделать что-то, т.к. он теперь ориентируется по верхнему краю элементов. Одновременно и сверху и снизу выровнять не получится никак.

Comment: В любом случае благодарен вам за помощь, очень качественно и подробно!

Comment: а как отслеживать видимость скрола?
И можно ли с ним взаимодействовать?
Как вы показывали в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788938/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-scrollbar-%d0%b2-scrollviewer?noredirect=1#comment1241917_788938)

Comment: присваивание имени не помогает(

Comment: @UporotayaPanda, а вы смотрите, как я с `PreviewMouseWheel` поступил. Здесь также можно: подпишитесь в разметке на `ScrollChanged`, а в методе-обработчике напишите `var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)sender;`