# Клавиатурная навигация в кастомном ScrollViewer`е

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть такая разметка:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="400" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerDefaultStyle}">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="_allTags" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=SearchTextBox}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:String}">
                <Button Template="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" PreviewKeyDown="PreviewHashTag_KeyDown" Click="Item_Click"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Есть код, который при нажатии Down в текстовом поле(код не привожу) переносит фокус в ItemsControl, где потом можно свободно было перемещаться между айтемами с помощью стрелок. Но так было пока я не прописал стиль: ScrollViewerDefaultStyle

Стиль:

```
<Style x:Key="ScrollViewerDefaultStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <ScrollContentPresenter KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                                            CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>

                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarStyle}"
                        Orientation="Vertical"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                        Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                        ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarStyle}"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                        Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                        ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

После того, как я применил стиль, при нажатии Down, фокус переносится, но навигация происходит не по айтемам, а по всему ScrollViewer, т.е. происходит простая прокрутка. Не могу понять что за это отвечает.

Игрался с KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation, но это ни к чему не привело.
Помогите разобраться.

Comment: В стандартном стиле нет вообще `KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation`

Comment: А вообще вы используете неправильный подход, для того, чтобы скроллить элементы внутри ItemsControl, нужно, чтобы ScrollViewer был внутри него, а не снаружи. Посмотрите этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/790433/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP Перенёс ScrollViewer в ItemsControl, теперь при нажатии Down видно, что фокус приходит на первый элемент как и раньше, но последующие нажатия стрелок приводят к простой прокрутке

Comment: Кстати, а почему вы считаете, что переход между контролами должен выполняться по клавише "Вниз"? Стандартный способ перехода между контролами - клавиша "Tab"

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я основываюсь на том, что было при дефолтном поведении, до того как я применил стиль. Мне достаточно было просто передать фокус в ItemsControl и просто перемещаться стрелками, как вверх-вниз, так и влево-вправо

Comment: Понял проблему, смотрите ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стандартном шаблоне `ScrollViewer` скроллируемая область имеет наименование `PART_ScrollContentPresenter`, вы в своем шаблоне эту область не обозначили, поэтому у вас сейчас содержимое отдельно, а область прокрутки отдельно. Просто назначьте соответствующее наименование:

```
<ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" ...
```

[Стили и шаблоны элемента ScrollViewer](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/scrollviewer-styles-and-templates)

Comment: Точно, спасибо! А почему дело в имени? Оно где-то в потрохах используется?

Comment: Именно! Ответственные за функционал части шаблона внутри контрола ищутся по имени. Если какого-то имени нет, значит контрол эту часть функционала не поддерживает.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Теперь при переопределении шаблонов буду это учитывать.